# foreignAutoCreate not working?

Tags: android, ormlite

In my project, I have cached foreign annotations and did all insert and delete cascading manually, but I am now trying to update my code to use the new foreignAutoCreate annotation and I noticed a few issues. The first one is that DatabaseFieldConfigLoader does not add this field to the generated config file. The appropriate code would seem to be missing around line 212 of version 4.29 of that class.

Even after manually adding the definition to the config file, it seems that it does not get correctly set when loading the config file. On line 102 of the MappedCreate class, tableInfo.isForeignAutoCreate() returns false for classes that do have the annotation set

For reference, this is how I declared my class member:

```
@DatabaseFieldSimple
@DatabaseFieldForeign(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh=true, foreignAutoCreate=true)
public Response response;
```

And my child class Response has the following id field

```
@DatabaseFieldSimple
@DatabaseFieldId(generatedId = true)
public int id;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `foreignAutoRefresh` field (and also `version`) are not being configured correctly using the `DatabaseFieldConfigLoader` -- both for reading and writing of the class configuration.  I've opened [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3433599&group_id=297653&atid=1255989#) and fixed it in trunk.  The fix was added to [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) in version 4.30.

I've added comments to the end of @DatabaseField to [hopefully] protect from this in the future.

Sorry for the bug.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the reply and I look forward to the update.

Comment: So I updated to the latest build (4.30) but I still finding that the foreignAutoCreate is not working as I expected it to. It seems that the foreign objects are in fact created but the id fields in the parent object are never updated. Should I ping the mailing list with some code examples?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-create) will be very useful, check notes on using (foreignAutoCreate = true) which are :

1. (foreignAutoCreate = true) work only if the ID field is not set (null or 0) according to ORMlite documentation http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html

   foreignAutoCreate : "Set this to be true (default false) to have the foreign field will be automagically created using its internal DAO if the ID field is not set (null or 0)."
2. This only works if generatedId is also set to true for the child table according to [ORMlite documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-auto-create).